# Creation of instance of PdfReader throws exception and crash the program

Tags: java, itext

While reading different pdf documents, I have faced with a problem, which is really diffucult to find its reason. I have just run the below source code for two pdf whose properties shown below, and I have got the number of page. However, whenever I have read the third one which is marked with * (PDF 2), my program is crached and I couldnot caught the thrown null exception. My wonder is that why program is crashing and why I can't catch the thrown exception. Moreover, How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE:

itext version: itext 5.5.1
  document is purchased, and the claimer is restricts me to share with third person or in the web site

Document properties

```
 Abbreviation: A: ALLOWED   NA: NOT ALLOWED    NS: NO SECURİTY  AV: ALL VERSION

                                    PDF 1   PDF 2                 PDF 3
                                             *
printing                            | A     A                       A
document assembly                   | NA    NA                      NA
content copying                     | A     A                       A
content copying for accessibility   | A     A                       A
page extraction                     | NA    NA                      NA
commenting                          | A     NA                      A
filling of form fields              | A     NA                      A
signing                             | NA    NA                      NA
creation of template pages          | A     NA                      A
security mode                       | NS    PASSWORD SECURITY       NS
can be opened by                    | AV    ACROBAT 7.0 AND LATER   AV
tagged pdf                          | YES   NO                      NO

                                            ^
                                            ^
                Note of PDF 2: All contents of document are encrypted and search engine cannot access the document's metadata
```

The code

```
    PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    try {
        RandomAccessFile rAF = new RandomAccessFile(this.openFilePath, "r");
        RandomAccessSourceFactory sF = new RandomAccessSourceFactory();
        RandomAccessFileOrArray rA = new RandomAccessFileOrArray( sF.createSource(rAF));

        System.out.println("[DEBUG] - 4");
        System.out.flush();
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(rA, null);

        System.out.println("[DEBUG] - 5");
        System.out.flush();
        this.totalPage = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();

        System.out.println("[DEBUG] - 6");
        System.out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Technical Exception
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] - 7");
        System.out.flush();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] - In finally clause");
        System.out.flush(); 

line 179        pdfReader.close();

        System.out.println("[DEBUG] - Near Out of finally clause");
        System.out.flush();
    }
    System.out.printf("[DEBUG] - pdfReader\n");
    System.out.flush();
```

Thrown Exception

```
[DEBUG] - 4
[DEBUG] - In finally clause
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at extractTotalPageNo(ControlCenter.java:179)
    at control(ControlCenter.java:99)
    at Manage.main(Management.java:22)
```

Comment: `System.out.flush();` - Never seen before - thanks - what is use of it ?

Comment: @NinadPingale, my program is based totaly on thread pool. I use it for the sake of not to accumulate outputs in the buffer.

Comment: Ok.Shall make use of it.Thanks.

Comment: Does this occur with all your PDFs? If not, then there may be a bug in the PDF. Show us the PDF. Which version of iText are you using? In the most recent versions, we're replacing `NullPointerException`s with `InvalidPdfException`s that give you an indication of the error in the PDF file.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie not all of them, I have seen in the one document (PDF 2). I have updated the question as you wish.

Comment: Why is the line "[DEBUG] - 7" not output?

Comment: @JamesB really, I don't know. I don't understand why exception is not captured. Interestingly, after finally clause, the program exit.

Comment: Remove the line pdfReader.close and re-post that output please

Comment: @JamesB I am not in the home. Code is in the home machine. So Sorry for this type of inconvenience.

Comment: @Zmavus You should accept Henry's answer. The reason your exception block is not hit is because of the NPE in the finally block (pdfReader is null). To uncover the real exception, add a null check (as Henry has suggested) and re-run. This run will output the stacktrace of the problem which is occurring when the PdfReader constructor is called.

Comment: If you can't share the PDF, then nobody can help you. You have established that the problem doesn't occur with all PDF documents, just the one you can't share. Note that you're using iText 5.5.1 which may imply that you have a commercial license with us (if you're using iText in a commercial context). Our customers can share documents with us on our closed ticketing system. We guarantee that the document won't be forwarded to other people.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie It is just a hobby project. Who will buy the pdf extractor program. I just want to learn Pdf and and extraction method. If you want the document to analyse better, I will share with you as soon as possible.

Comment: If it's a hobby project, please say so in advance. Now it just looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. iText already has parser classes that spider through the content stream of a page and the XObjects that are referred to from that page. It also looks into the unicode mappings stored in the font. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE to understand why fonts are also important!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have solved the problem. It is related with not installing bouncycastle package to my program. Since there is no package, the compiler complains, crashes my program and finishes its job. As a result, the reason why the other printf is not called  is th class not found error.

Comment: OK, it's strange you didn't see a stack trace for the `ClassNotFoundException` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run the program with @Henry suggestion.

Afterwards, I realized that the system actually results in an error because I forgot to add the BouncyCastle jars to my CLASSPATH. package. When the program tries to read encrypted documents, it calls, I assume, encryption functionality from iText's `PdfReader` constructor.

Moreover, since iText has a dependency on BouncyCastle, the java compiler complains about not having found the class with the encryption function that is called.

In conclusion, the solution is to add the BouncyCastle jar to my CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

From the output it seems that there was a problem in this line

```
pdfReader = new PdfReader(rA, null);
```

and `pdfreader` never got set to something not `null`.

This leads to the NPE when you try to access it in line 179 and therefore hides the root cause which seems to be a `Throwable` but not an `Exception` because it is not caught.

You can make the close conditional:

```
if (pdfreader != null) {
    pdfReader.close();
}
```

Comment: I have used the `pdfReader = new PdfReader(rA, new byte[0]);`, but it result in the same problem, so I have changed.

Comment: Now that I understand the problem, this is the right answer. pdfReader must be null in the finally block

Comment: @JamesB why pdfReader must be null. For Pdf 1 and PDf 3, it is not null. But, for Pdf 2, it is null

Comment: @Zmavus There must be a problem with Pdf 2 which throws an exception from the PdfReader class. If you implement Henry's suggestion, you will find out the real exception.

Comment: @JamesB thanks for your help. I will try, but one question why the `catch exception clause` is not caught the thrown exception.

Comment: That also puzzles me. You should see either `[DEBUG] - 5` or `[DEBUG] - 7`. Not seeing any of those seems very strange to me.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I will run with above suggestion and If I solve it, I will share it.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:
In our case it was authorization issue that cause SAP-PI to crash when trying to read the PDF file.
This means that this class was not built correctly, if authorization causing the Constructor to crash without issuing Exception.